SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer)
I sometimes get the exception "SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer)" in my dart server which uses websockets. This leads to the server process terminating. How do I catch the exception to continue the process?
  static Future<void> init() async {
    SecurityContext? securityContext;
    var server;
    if (Env.certificateChainPath != null && Env.privateKeyPath != null) {
      securityContext = SecurityContext()
        ..usePrivateKeyBytes(File(Env.privateKeyPath!).readAsBytesSync())
        ..useCertificateChainBytes(File(Env.certificateChainPath!).readAsBytesSync());
      server = await HttpServer.bindSecure(Env.local ? "localhost" : InternetAddress.anyIPv6, Env.wsPort, securityContext);
    } else {
      server = await HttpServer.bind(Env.local ? "localhost" : InternetAddress.anyIPv6, Env.wsPort);
    }

    await for (var request in server) {
        if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)) {
          WebSocket ws = await WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request);
          // ...
        }
    }
  }
 


I'm a little rusty on dart, but I'd expect that you can do a try...on.
